# How to deserialize a BsonDocument object back to class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I deserialize a BsonDocument object back to the class after getting it from the server?

```
QueryDocument _document = new QueryDocument("key", "value");
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> _documentsReturned = _collection.FindAs<BsonDocument>(_document);

foreach (BsonDocument _document1 in _documentsReturned)
{
    //deserialize _document1
    //?
}
```

Do I deserialize using a BsonReader?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There are three ways actually:

1.Specify type you want to load directly in `FindAs<>`

```
var docs = _collection.FindAs<MyType>(_document);
```

2.Deserialize document via `BsonSerializer`:

```
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(doc);
```

3.Map bson document manually to your class:

```
var myClass = new Mytype();
myClass.Name = bsonDoc["name"].AsString;
```

For most cases you  are okay with first approach. But sometimes, when your documents is unstructured, you may need third approach.

Comment: An error occurred while deserializing the Property1 property of class Class1: ReadString can only be called when CurrentBsonType is String, not when CurrentBsonType is ObjectId. I put the bson objectid to guid of the class and mapped the class. How should I fix this?

Comment: @iefpw: Error say that you have different types of Property1 in database and in class (objectId in database and string in class).

Comment: I was trying to deserialize to the wrong class. Add "ObjectId Id { get; set; } to the class and basically everything works without class mapping.

Comment: `FindAs<>()` is not on the interface `IMongoCollection` which is what comes back from `GetCollection()`. Is this an old answer and the method no longer exists or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For big applications and which has some structured data, it's recommended to use your custom model while creating and getting the data instead of using BsonDocument.

Creating a model is an important step for deserialization.

Helpful annotations to remember while creating your model:

- add `id` property in model. Try to use `[BsonId]` attribute for good practice:
- Create a property with annotation as `[BsonExtraElements]` this will be used to hold any extra elements found during deserialization.
- you can use `[BsonElement]` to specify the elementName.
- `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` - Initializes a new instance of the BsonIgnoreIfDefaultAttribute class

**Sample Model structure**, where I tried to cover maximum cases. I have created a base class for _id property just for better architecture, but you can use directly in `MyModel` class as well.

```
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        // if you'd like to delegate another property to map onto _id then you can decorate it with the BsonIdAttribute, like this
        [BsonId]
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel: BaseEntity
    {
        [BsonElement("PopulationAsOn")]
        public DateTime? PopulationAsOn { get; set; }
    
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [BsonElement("CountryId")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [StringLength(5)]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public virtual string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public IList<States> States { get; set; }

        [BsonExtraElements]
        public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
    }
```

Now to Deserialise, directly use your model while calling `FindAsync` like this:

```
cursor = await _collection.FindAsync(filter, 
new FindOptions<MyModel, MyModel>() 
{ BatchSize = 1000, Sort = sort }, ct);
```