# What is the other way around of ToBsonDocument?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, bson

Say I have a business. If I want to turn an object whose class is Business into a BsonDocument, I would do

```
aBusiness.ToBsonDocument
```

Great.

What about if I want to turn a BsonDocument into aBusiness class? Is there an easy way?

**Public Shared Function ToBsonDocument(Of TNominalType)(ByVal obj As TNominalType) As MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument
     Member of MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is deserialize your BSonDocument into your class.

Without having a more complete view of your class I can't give a full example, but in general you would need to do something like:

```
Dim testBusiness As aBusiness = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of aBusiness)
```

You can find the API documentation for the BSonSerializer [here](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/61e85ebb-2cd2-33fe-d6d7-f394a35e6bcb.htm)

You can also see a similar question for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478613/)