# How to deserialize a Bson document to a POCO?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, poco, bson, json-deserialization

I'm using the [Mongo .Net Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/getting_started/quick_tour/) to query a MongoDB database and I want to map the returned Bson document to my Customer Object Poco.

In order to do this I created a `LoadCustomers()` to return a de-serialized list of customers from the queried Bson document.

In my Customer POCO class, each property is marked with `BsonElement` tag which should assist the mapping of Bson to Object.

But when I tried to deserialize using the FindAs<> from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478613/how-to-deserialize-a-bsondocument-object-back-to-class) , I get a compiler error stating that there is no such method.

How can I return the MongoDB Bson document as a POCO list, using MongoDB .Net driver?

This is my current attempt at the load method:

```
    public static List<Customer> LoadCustomers()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
        //Get a handle on the customers collection:
        var docs = database.FindAs<Customer>("customers");
        return docs;            
    }
```

Below is my Customer POCO, showing the fields within the document:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This attribute is used to map the Id property to the ObjectId in the collection
        /// </summary>
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("firstName")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("lastName")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest driver, First you have to get the collection and then do your query on the collection. Something like this

```
public static List<Customer> LoadCustomers()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
    //Get a handle on the customers collection:
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Customer>("customers");
    var docs = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return docs;            
}
```

Comment: I now need to return a list from a new collection I have, but not sure how to return just the list from the Model. I posted a question on it if you have any advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077614/how-to-fetch-a-list-of-values-from-a-bson-document

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select all Customers in a Collection use something like this:

```
var docs = await database.GetCollection<Customer>("customers").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

For querying a single document by id, something like this should be used:

```cs
var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Id, <ID>);
var result = await database.GetCollection<Customer>("customers").Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: In case of does not match any field or property of class (i.e. _class or _id) error keep in mind to annotate POCO with [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]