# MongoDB ObjectId conversion error in c# using Newtonsoft Deserialization

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver, newtonscript

I have been working to convert MongoDB BSON documents to List object in c#.
While converting, i get below error

```
"{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '_id', line 1, position 10."}"
```

After searching for similar issues in stackoverflow, i found below link

[JSON.NET cast error when serializing Mongo ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651776/json-net-cast-error-when-serializing-mongo-objectid)

and i followed the same.

**My Code:**

Sample Entity/Model

```
public class BTMObj
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MongoDataSerializer))]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string requestFormat { get; set; }
}

public class MongoDataSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ObjectId);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                String.Format("Unexpected token parsing ObjectId. Expected String, got {0}.",
                              reader.TokenType));
        }

        var value = (string)reader.Value;
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? ObjectId.Empty : new ObjectId(value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is ObjectId)
        {
            var objectId = (ObjectId)value;

            writer.WriteValue(objectId != ObjectId.Empty ? objectId.ToString() : String.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected ObjectId value.");
        }
    }
}

public List<T> GetMongoCollection<T>(string collectionName)
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        var client = new MongoClient(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MONGO_CONNECTION"]));
        var database = client.GetDatabase(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MONGO_DB"]));
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
        var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            try
            {
                list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(document.ToJson()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Call to Method

```
list = mongoDBOperations.GetMongoCollection<BTMObj>(Collection);
```

MongoDataSerializer class overridden methods should get call which is not the case.
Our need is to get ObjectId as string in Model.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Sample document.toJson() value

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("611cf42e1e4c89336b6fe2f0"),
  "requestFormat": "json"
}
```

Comment: please share the value of `document.ToJson()`

Comment: @viveknuna - Added document.ToJson() value

Answer (score 1):

You only used [half of the relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651776/json-net-cast-error-when-serializing-mongo-objectid).

If you write this JSON:

```
  "_id": ObjectId("611cf42e1e4c89336b6fe2f0"),
  "requestFormat": "json"
}
```

As `BsonObject.ToJson()` does, then that's not JSON. The `ObjectId(...)` dialect, just as `Date()`, `NumberLong()`, `NumberInt()` and `NumberDecimal()` are constructs that make MongoDB spit out invalid JSON, because it's a *representation* of its internal BSON storage format.

So if you want to treat it as JSON, write valid JSON. The code is right there in the link: you need to serialize the object yourself. See [How to deserialize a BsonDocument object back to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478613/how-to-deserialize-a-bsondocument-object-back-to-class).

First make sure the Mongo C# driver deserializes the BSON into your POCO:

```
// Prefer using statically-typed extension methods such as 
// _collection.FindAs<MyType>()
var deserialized = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BTMobj>(document);
```

Then serialize that object to JSON using your converter:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized);
```

Your output will then become the very parseable:

```
  "_id": "611cf42e1e4c89336b6fe2f0",
  "requestFormat": "json"
}
```

And your type's metadata (attributes) will tell the parser to parse "611cf42e1e4c89336b6fe2f0" as a `BsonObjectId` when you try to deserialize it into a `BTMobj` again.

Comment: For me  var deserialized = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BTMobj>(document); does not work because every value from mongodb i need to get it as JSON and with above Mongo object types(integer) values does not get converted to c# object types. That is the reason i used it as JsonConvert.Deserialize. So like i have an int value for one of the key in BSON document that does not get converted to c# string.

Comment: Your problem is Mongo's ToJson(), you can't feed that to a proper JSON parser. It's its own dialect.